# StoryBoard Application not working after renaming app delegagte

Tags: ios, storyboard, appdelegate

I had an existing project using storyboard technique, I had to add an SDK to it and had to rename my AppDelegate.m to AppDelegate.mm

after renaming I get the following error if I run the Application.

There is no appdelegate set: Ann App delegate class must be specified to use a main story borad file

regards
Sikander

Comment: what does your main() function look like (in `main.m`)? Particularly the function `UIApplicationMain()`? What SDK did you add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I tried de-ARCing my project (long story) and copied some code I found on the web over my main function.  It turned out I had replaced this:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([cAppDelegate class]));
```

with this:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Putting it back to the previous way got it working again.